# Launch RDP silently?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, freerdp

I currently use the following command to launch an RDP session which works fine:

```
rds@rds:~/Downloads/FreeRDP$ xfreerdp /v:farm.company.com /d:company.com /g:rds.company.com /f /u:username /p:
```

At the moment, it displays all the following and I have to accept the certificate twice.

```
creating directory /home/rds/.config/freerdp
creating directory /home/rds/.config/freerdp/certs
creating directory /home/rds/.config/freerdp/server
Certificate details:
    Subject: OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.company.com
    Issuer: C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
    Thumbprint: ab:5a:03:f5:23:06:ad:76:57:e0:4a:2c:1f:be:04:b8:13:5c:32:55
The above X.509 certificate could not be verified, possibly because you do not have the CA certificate in your certificate store, or the certificate has expired. Please look at the documentation on how to create local certificate store for a private CA.
Do you trust the above certificate? (Y/N) Y
Password: 
Certificate details:
    Subject: OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.company.com
    Issuer: C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
    Thumbprint: ab:5a:03:f5:23:06:ad:76:57:e0:4a:2c:1f:be:04:b8:13:5c:32:55
The above X.509 certificate could not be verified, possibly because you do not have the CA certificate in your certificate store, or the certificate has expired. Please look at the documentation on how to create local certificate store for a private CA.
Do you trust the above certificate? (Y/N) 
Do you trust the above certificate? (Y/N) Y
```

Can this be changed so I only get prompted for the password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always wrap it with an `expect` script which provides automatic answers to the "trust" questions.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--from-stdin` parameter (e.g. with `yes` command) to prevent FreeRDP from asking the user questions such as verification of the certificates. Or use `/cert-ignore` client argument (not recommended).

Comment: `/cert-ignore` has been deprecated, one could use `/cert:ignore` to ignore certificates or `/cert:tofu` to automatically trust certificates, or `/cert:deny` to trust only certificates that can be validated else deny others